# How to give priority to page than to posts permalink structure?

Tags: posts, permalinks, pages

I have a site where I have the following permalink structure:

`/blog/%category%/%postname%/`

This has been set in the Settings -> Permalink Settings.

I also have a page named /blog/. This page gives me the access to all my posts. The problem I encounter is when you try to paginate in the /blog page, since the pagination link looks like this:

`https://www.mywebsite.com/blog/page/2/`

It takes me to a 404 since, I think, the link matchets the posts permalink structure.

Do you know how to make the pagination in /blog work and still have my posts permalink structure?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have, I guess, it is because you run a secondary query inside the "Blog" page to get the blog layout, but you should not do that. Instead, go to "wp-admin/options-reading.php" and set the "Posts page" to the `Blog` page. Now, the Blog page will use the [home.php or index.php template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) and the query for posts will be executed by WordPerss,you don't need a custom query to build the blog.